# How can I detect focus in textfields in a webview using Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, wkwebview

I am building an application, and when I load a website in webview using Swift 3, the screen will appear like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDUGX.png), now I want to detect when user clicks on the email text field, and add a button to the navigation controller.

I don't know how to do it, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I've proposed an edit to make the question a bit more readable - I hope I didn't misunderstand anything you wrote. Feel free to reject or amend my edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main use of webview is near like an iframe in web.

I mean that webview is just a displaying of internet content. By this way, you cannot detect any action like user clicks on email textfield.

According to me and currently, there is no possibility to do that because it is not the goal of a webview.

Comment: thanks, i know some application they can do that, but still have no idea

Comment: np, do you have any example of app? I will check, may be I can help :) Are you sure that is done on Facebook login page ?

Because I don't think that what you want to do it's made directly in Swift part of the app. It's done on the web part. I mean that website have mobile an 'm.website.com' version that detect when you are displaying their website using a phone and they put some interaction when you press this button or this field, and so on. You get it ?

Comment: you can try Keeper application :)

Comment: Do you have the link please ? :)

Comment: Are you still here buddy ?

Comment: sorry, i just wake up, you can go to appstore and download Keeper :(